# Adding client side unobtrusive validation rules in iframe content on load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, iframe

*Environment context: ASP.NET MVC 5 and jquery unobtrusive validation*

We have some user defined fields that are required for some users and not others.
As such, based on the current user's account, I am trying to add client side only validation rules that will behave just like the server side data annotation rules. But maybe this is the wrong approach? Maybe I should create a custom data annotation validation rule server side then let the client side take care of itself?

Anyway, this is what I have:

```
function validateWorkOrderFormOnLoad() {

    //Parses the new form for unobtrusive validation
    var $form = $('form');

    if (intAccountId === 1) {
        //MUST INITIALIZE THE VALIDATOR FIRST
        var validator = $form.validate();

        $("#WOHdr_Attribute3").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: attribute3 + " is Required."
            }
        });

        $("#WOHdr_Attribute4").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: attribute4 + " is Required."
            }
        });
    }
    //$form.removeData('validator');
    //$form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
    var isValid = $form.valid();
}
```

Which gets called on doc load of the iframe content (not the parent):

```
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        validateWorkOrderFormOnLoad();
    }, 2000);
     
});
```

And this works. But as you can see, I have to put in a delay, which I don't like and smells a bit hacky.

I've tried calling this method from the iframe load event:

```
$iframe.load(function () { validateWorkOrderFormOnLoad(); });
```

and this from withing a script tab in the iframe content page:

```
window.onload = function () {
   var $form = $("#frmWorkOrderHdr");
   parent.validateWorkOrderFormOnLoad($form);
}
```

and on the iframe onload event:

```
<iframe style="border:0px;width:100%;height:100px;display:none;" onload="validateWorkOrderFormOnLoad(this)" src=""></iframe>
```

None of these methods work, unless I put in a delay. What am I missing? Which event should call this method to show the errors on form load?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was testing this on a form that was hidden at the time of load and by default, validation doesn't validate hidden elements. So I had to tell it NOT to ignore hidden elements by setting the ignore list to empty:

```
$form.validate().settings.ignore
```

The reason why it worked with the delay, is the form would get displayed sometime after load and before the event fired with the delay.